# Fedora 30: Laptop hard shuts down on lid close

Tags: linux, laptop, fedora, chromebook

I've been having this problem since I upgraded to fedora 30 a week ago, and I've been continuously updating it each day and searching forums for solutions with no luck.

What's been happening, is each time I close the lid it's as if I pulled the plug on the machine. I've tried to find how I can maybe change a setting or something as to what either may be causing it or how to solve.

I should mention that this is an Acer Chromebook 14 that I've set up with SeaBIOS to run Fedora.

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I can't answer your question but FWI I'm running Fedora 30 Silverblue with no issues on a Dell 13 Chromebook using the Mr. Chromebox firmware.